# What is the Unknown (0) process with 232 threads on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, activity-monitor, malware

Here's a list of the processes on iPhone, obtained with help of Activity Monitor in Xcode instruments.

Is the Unknown(0) process with 232 threads owned by root malware?

[image: Activity Monitor screenshot]

Comment: I’ve edited the side question on lists malware names out. We strongly prefer one question per question. It would be very appropriate and encouraged to ask a linked question that focuses on that topic.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to think they're OS internals with which Apple thinks we're too dumb to interact.  (So yeah malware, as they're iOS).  ;)

Comment: @AdamBarnes why not put up a proper answer? Criticism is welcome - especially when it can be backed up with a reference or some argument. I did edit the comment so it’s not directed at any “you”.

Comment: I just wanted to make a little jokey joke and brighten up people's day a little.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`pid 0` is always `kernel_task` in xnu. Further corroborated by being owned by root and having a lot of threads. It’s a synthetic process structure that represents the kernel. It isn’t malware.

Comment: Couldn't a rootkit impersonate the kernel?

Comment: @Sevron Yes, but there's nothing suspicious here about this process.

Comment: what _would_ a suspicious process look like?

Comment: Odd for something with a well-established identity to be labeled `Unknown`.

Comment: I agree with @Nat's comment, but FWIW my Activity Monitor shows the name as `kernel_task`

Comment: +1 Also, considering that launchd is responsible for everything else except pid 0, and pid 0 is responsible for launchd, this implies that this is the kernel, which would load before any other task on virtually any multitasking OS design.